# GooglePlaces Sample project ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

Tags: android-studio, google-places-api

I had this error when I was trying to run the google PlacesComplete and PlacePicker sample projects:

" ...\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\7.3.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file "

Android studio was unable to open the common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png file.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I moved the project folder directory up a level or two to reduce path length. Everything worked perfectly after that.

For example, I used "D:\the_project_folder". Worked for me. No more compile errors.

Credit to this link:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions/issues/2

I hope this helps someone out there.

Cheers!